# Setting up SendGrid with ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to set up SendGrid with my MVC ASP.net application this is the first time I have used it. I have tried to Authenticate with a SendGrid API Key but I am not sure if I am doing it right, I have tried to find the name of the environment variable for my SendGrid key but I don't know what it is or where it is or how to find it and I can't seem to find any information about it online.
I keep getting the following error:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: apiKey
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: apiKey

Source Error:


Line 30:         {
Line 31:             var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/api_keys/API1");
Line 32:             var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
Line 33:             var from = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");
Line 34:             var subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";

Source File: C:\Users\M\source\repos\AssessmentTask2\AssessmentTask2\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs    Line: 32
```

Here is the code for the file I have tried following a few tutorials changed the code multiple times but I can/t seem to fix it

Code: ideintityconfig.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using AssessmentTask2.Models;
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;

namespace AssessmentTask2
{
    public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            await configSendGridasync(message);
        }
        //SG.uSDrb4hJQmKPJbTNr_eW2w.lMMbl1c5P8rxdn6cwBr3xdrqXun
        static async Task configSendGridasyn(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NAME_OF_THE_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_FOR_YOUR_SENDGRID_KEY");
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var from = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");
            var subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
            var to = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");
            var plainTextContent = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";
            var htmlContent = "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with C#</strong>";
            var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);

            if (client != null)
            {
                await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
            }
            else
            {
                Trace.TraceError("Failed to create Web transport.");
                await Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public class SmsService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            // Plug in your SMS service here to send a text message.
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }

    // Configure the application user manager used in this application. UserManager is defined in ASP.NET Identity and is used by the application.
    public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
            : base(store)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
            // Configure validation logic for usernames
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };

            // Configure validation logic for passwords
            manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
                RequireDigit = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = true,
            };

            // Configure user lockout defaults
            manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
            manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

            // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
            // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                Subject = "Security Code",
                BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
            manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
            var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
            if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
            {
                manager.UserTokenProvider = 
                    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
            }
            return manager;
        }
    }

    // Configure the application sign-in manager which is used in this application.
    public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
    {
        public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
            : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
        {
        }

        public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
        }

        public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like your API key is not set in your environment and if it is, it is not called "https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/api_keys/API1".
Remember if you run from IIS it's probably as an Application Pool and it has it's own environment. So you have to set it System Wide for AppPools to access it.
Try and set it directly in your code until you confirm it works. Then figure out why you can't access that environment variable.

Comment: Did you try to use configuration file to store the API Key to start with? have you received the API Key from the SendGrid? Where have you stored it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1:
Generate your API key from dashboard->EmailAPI [image]  https://app.sendgrid.com/guide/integrate/langs/csharp

Step2: Creating environment variable refer this https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10